# Updating MySQL Table via contents of tab delimited text file (Through PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, casting

So I'm having a ridiculous amount of difficulties with this, apart from the fact that PHP is not multithreaded, which honestly is probably the only good thing happening with this right now.

Recently my company changed to a new database. With our old database, we were updating our mysql records (don't ask why we have a database PLUS mysql) through the use of a very old Python program which really didn't work. Now with the new database implemented, I had the opportunity to do away with Python altogether and I decided to work with PHP in translating the information from our new database.

That said, the method we're using is exporting stuff like quantities, prices, all the like from this new database to excel, then saving the file out as a tab delimited text file. I pop these files into a folder and run a .bat file, which calls my php program, which reads the three files, stores everything in arrays, translates the contents of these arrays into MySQL prepared statements, and then putting this information into MySQL one item at a time. In all it takes about 10 minutes, which is actually fine- the python script used to take upwards 6 hours.

As of right now, I'm not too worried about the speed. There was a lot of testing for me in this script, and refining it can come later. The part that's causing me issues (i.e. the **TLDR**) is that some fields are not updating, and it took me AGES to figure out why.

I have several Price fields set as float fields. The reason why is because the contents of those fields will be sent to the contents of another table, which are floats, and I cannot change the types of that table. That table is basically the "do not touch or change any of this because it's the bible table". All of the other tables are built to accommodate that one. The prices being sent into the text file, as well as the quantities, and basically any number field, are being saved as **strings**, not floats or ints.

First thing I did was look up casting, and I've tried the following:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table1(modelNumber, itemName, UPC, OnHand, IsCommitted, OnOrder, quantity, mfgr_num, unitOfMeasure, modelDescription, weight, frozenFor, discontinued, dropship) VALUES (?, ?, ?, CAST(? AS DECIMAL(10, 0)), CAST(? AS DECIMAL(10, 0)), CAST(? AS DECIMAL(10, 0)), CAST(? AS DECIMAL(10, 0)), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $mod);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $item);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $u);

    $stmt->bindParam(4, $onh);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $isCommitted);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $order);

    $stmt->bindParam(7, $in);
    $stmt->bindParam(8, $mfgr);
    $stmt->bindParam(9, $measure);
    $stmt->bindParam(10, $deets);
    $stmt->bindParam(11, $w);
    $stmt->bindParam(12, $fro);
    $stmt->bindParam(13, $dis);
    $stmt->bindParam(14, $dr);

    $onh = $inStock2[$i];           // 1
    $isCommitted = $committed[$i];  // 2
    $order = $ordered[$i];          // 3
    $mod = $modelNumber02[$i];      // 4
    $item = $itemName[$i];          // 5
    $u = $upc[$i];                  // 6
    $in = $onh - $isCommitted;      // 7
    $mfgr = $mfgr_num[$i];          // 8
    $measure = $uom[$i];            // 9
    $deets = $itemDeets[$i];        // 10
    $w = $weight[$i];               // 11
    $fro = $frozenFor[$i];          // 12
    $dis = $disc[$i];               // 13
    $dr = $drop[$i];                // 14
```

I tried selecting some things via that type of cast, and it seemed to work all right... Except it didn't. One particular example field I'm watching should be filled with 2,032. In the text file, it reads "2,032", with the quotes. So the field gets filled with 0 in MySQL.

There are three other instances that look just like the one above. I've tried a very simplistic approach by attempting to convert the fields in Excel to float... But that didn't appear to work. Like at all.

SO. Advice? Am I missing something? Did I just type the cast wrong? Am I barking up the wrong tree? And yes, I realize this is one huge Insert. The table it's being inserted to acts like a temp table, though it's never deleted.

Edit: Example of data attempting to be placed in the table. This ("2032.00") is the only field **that I have seen** that has quotations. The fields below it aren't updating either.

```
841 1333    0.00    0.00    0.00
842 1334    0.00    0.00    0.00
843 1338    0.00    0.00    0.00
844 1339    0.00    0.00    0.00
845 1340    0.00    0.00    0.00
846 1341    0.00    0.00    0.00
847 1344    "2,032.00"  7.00    0.00
848 1345    95.00   0.00    300.00
849 1345EA  60.00   0.00    0.00
850 1346    733.00  41.00   200.00
851 1346EA  67.00   0.00    0.00
852 1348    7.00    0.00    400.00
853 1348EA  21.00   0.00    0.00
854 1349    348.00  1.00    400.00
855 1350    91.00   1.00    300.00
856 1350EA  60.00   0.00    0.00
857 1351    0.00    0.00    1.00
858 1354    10.00   0.00    0.00
859 1357    4.00    12.00   6.00
860 1358    0.00    2.00    1.00
861 1360    0.00    0.00    0.00
862 1361    0.00    0.00    0.00
863 1362    0.00    0.00    0.00
864 1363    0.00    0.00    0.00
865 1364    0.00    0.00    24.00
866 1365    3.00    0.00    24.00
867 1366    0.00    2.00    1.00
```

Edit 2.0: I changed the FLOAT fields to VARCHAR in an attempt to see if they'd make it to the table I want them to get to. In so doing, I realized that the field is ACTUALLY including the Quotations with the numbers, even though the quotations aren't in the file to begin with. So it appears some of these fields might have added values to them that weren't there to begin with. I'm going to attempt to create an extraction and that may solve this as well.

Comment: "database PLUS mysql"? Mysql is database...

Comment: and note: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php   argument #3 - `$data_type`.

Comment: @MarcB, yes, I do know that. The wording is weird, but we ultimately don't treat MySQL as a database here- don't ask why, I've been pushing to remove the secondary database altogether, but the final decision was not to rely only on MySQL. So they treat it, basically, like it's a sort of... Idk, notekeeper. Ultimately, we have two databases. One runs off of SQL Server, and the other is MySQL. It's basically my hell on Earth.

Comment: @MarcB just noticed your second comment, it'd been a while since I had read the bindParam page. That may be just the thing I'm looking for

Comment: @MarcB that almost works. Unfortunately, there's no bind_param PDO::PARAM for a float/double. So I'm still stuck. Everything but my price fields will be accurately updated.

Comment: You can actually use the `load data infile` syntax if you say `load data LOCAL infile` and your program has access to where the file is locally stored, and your mysql user has permissions to use this functionality.

Comment: @RyanVincent the problem is that I wasn't using casting before now, and that's how I know the fields aren't updating. The file has the data. The arrays are filled with the data from the file, and the data just... Doesn't go to MySQL. And it's only fields from the file that have become strings. The casting is an attempt to fix that error.

Comment: @RyanVincent Obviously the casting isn't??? Why would it be working and I'd write a question about it? Did you read anything?

Comment: @RyanVincent Try refreshing then. I'm adding more because I'm actually attempting to figure this out while I wait for helpful suggestions, some of which I have received. I'll keep updating the question as I go. The table at the moment is out of sorts and no longer in its original state- once I've finished that I'll post its create.

Comment: @RyanVincent Thank you for jumping in- I did actually figure out the issue, and it wasn't what I'd thought it was. I had originally thought there was something I was missing in my PHP code, and that was why I came here, but it turns out it was something really ridiculous...

Comment: Sidenote: I thought this was one of the best-written and clearest questions I have read in a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out what was wrong with my program, though it wasn't what I had originally thought, which was that there was something I was missing.

Because some of the fields contained commas, they were turned into strings, and had quotations literally added onto the data when I converted it from an excel file to a tab-delimited text file. So a value that looked like 2,323 was turned into "2,323" in order to keep the comma.

Because the fields in MySQL for the table were FLOAT fields, and they can't read commas, I used the following to fix the values:

```
else if($i == 2 || ($i - 2) % $len3 == 0) {
    $stk = str_replace('"', '', $docContents3[$i]);
    $stk = str_replace(',', '', $stk);
    array_push($inStock2, $stk);
```

I removed the commas and the quotes, which fixed my issue with fields not updating properly, as even if I removed the quotes the commas caused MySQL to automatically truncate the information. So 2,323 became 2. Which is obviously VERY off.

Thank you to those who tried to help me and suffered through my lack of complete information- there were suggestions for topics I hadn't seen yet, and I now know I can actually just fill a table with the contents of a file, something I might use in the future to make this process smoother.

In other words... Punctuation. Literally Punctuation.

Comment: Gotta love a self-answered solution and a good explanation to boot ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you ^_^ I felt a bit silly. I had been so sure it was something in the method I was using, and it turned out to be punctuation. I wouldn't have come here had I seen the actual issue sooner >.>

Comment: You're very much welcome. You wouldn't believe the bad and/or badly asked/formed questions we see on Stack, it's pathetic. Plus, your grammar, spelling... *brava!!*  You were probably expecting "bravo", here right? Heh, well in Italian, "bravo" is for "men", compared to "brava" which is the feminin version and (equally) signifies that someone has done well. *Cheers* and keep up the good work.